# graphics card enhancement

Tags: drivers, 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have the following specs on my system76 laptop (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit)

- Intel® Iris™ Pro Graphics 5200
- 4th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-4750HQProcessor ( 2.0 GHz 6MB L3 Cache - 4 Cores plus Hyperthreading )
- 16 GB Dual Channel DDR3 SDRAM at 1600MHz - 2 X 8 GB

Is there any kind of software tweaks I can do to enhance the quality of the images that come in on my graphics card from when I play steam. Please suggest any kind of package(s) or modifications I can do that will give me a better picture/resolution/display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ian's right. Though you might be able to improve overall performance by making sure you have the latest drivers for your card.

[Head here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux) and download the Intel Graphics Installer for 14.04 64bit. It'll check your system and install any relevant updates.

Answer (score 1):

Quality and detail settings are actually set per-game within the game's own configuration screens. If you open up a specific game and click on "Settings", most games have a "Quality" or "Video" options screen where you can change the quality and resolution settings.